# Parent li is changing color in specific pages only

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a site implemented in wordpress using a responsive theme, all my custom styles and php files are in a child theme.

The issue is in the main navigation when you hover any child li of "Learn More" nav, the "Learn More" li is breaking and changing the color and it also loose its left border line. the weird thing is that it only happens on 2 pages of the website:

https://presslock.org/about/ and https://presslock.org/faq/

But on other pages it is working fine.

Thanks, any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: use page-id-60 page-id-656 ref. in css which is added by wp_function  in body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix : Just remove all the styling of the class `custom-menu-item` from your style.css file. Remove these two parts :

```
.menu .current_page_item a,.menu .current-menu-item a{background-color:#343434;}
```

and

```
.current-menu-item a{background-color:#F6BC01;background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#F6BC01,#F5E09A,#F6BC01);background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#F6BC01,#F5E09A,#F6BC01);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#F6BC01,#F5E09A,#F6BC01);background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#F6BC01,#F5E09A,#F6BC01);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#F6BC01,#F5E09A,#F6BC01);}
```

If you are interested in the reason for this problem it is as KnowHowSolutions stated, the problem is in the css properties at certain case. The properties of `custom-menu-item` is applied when you hover over the children of a menu item while your current page is this menu item . This happens also on the https://presslock.org/stats/ page when you hover over the children of "Resources" if you noted.

Hope this helps and excuse my English.

Answer (score 1):

These lines of css are applied on hover (plus a few others, Firebug is the best for inspecting these changes)

```
.menu li:hover a {
    color: #F5E09A;
}
.menu .current_page_item a, .menu .current-menu-item a {
    background-color: #343434;
}
.menu li a {
    color: #660033;
}
.menu a {
    border-left: 1px solid #585858;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0.6em;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000000;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.current-menu-item a {
    background-color: #F6BC01;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #F6BC01, #F5E09A, #F6BC01);
}
```

This last item doesn't apply background-color, but overrides it with background image, which is yellow.

Comment: Actually this is close but quite it.  Your gradient is only on a hover and appears that it shouldn't be applied on all the menu